# Суть конструктора по-умолчанию в наследовании

Tags: c#, .net, наследование

Здравствуйте. Зачем когда мы создаем какой-нибудь конструктор в базовом классе, обязательно надо создать еще и конструктор по-умолчанию, в противном случае не получается создавать объект унаследованного класса. Например, если в этом коде попытаемся комментировать конструктор по-умолчанию, выдается ошибка

```
using System;
class one
{
    private int ID;
    //public one() { }
    public one(int ID)
    {
        this.ID = ID;
    }
}
class two : one
{
    int age;string name, position;
    public two(int age, string name, string position)
    {
        this.age = age;
        this.name = name;
        this.position = position;
    }
    public void show()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(name + " " + position + " " + age);
    }
}
class consoleapp
{
    static void Main()
    {
        two obj = new two(25,"Shamil", "IT");
        obj.show();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: потому-что базовые класс требует от вас значение для поле 'id'. а вы не передаете базовому конструктору значение и поэтому получается синтаксическая ошибка.

Comment: Только прошу, называйте классы с большой буквы, функции тоже) Так принято в c#

Comment: Так у вас нет конструктора по умолчанию в базовом классе.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

На самом деле не обязательно.

При конструировании объекта производного класса мы обязаны вызвать конструктор базового и если вы не указываете какой конкретно конструктор нужно вызвать, то компилятор по умолчанию ищет конструктор без параметров.

Конкретно ваш код скомпилируется, если написать, например, так:

```
public two(int age, string name, string position) : base(1)
```

Comment: Зачем компилятор всегда должен искать конструктор в базовом классе ?

Comment: Чтобы инициализировать ту начинку, которая содержится в базовом классе, очевидно

Comment: Если вы не допишете в конструкторе производного класса `: base(...)`, то компилятор допишет сам `: base()`, но так как пустого конструктора нет - это не скомпилируется